# Can we create a floating kind of view on a button click?

Tags: android

Please refer to the attachment. I am not able to create such a view on a button or spinner click such that the view is attached with the button/spinner
If i click on attachment or that lock on the bottom left corner, a view should appear like this. If i use spinner , it appears normally like it does. Is it possible to do like this ?
I have updated the snapshot.. I want this view in the red portion. It should be a single view expanding like this.
[image]

Comment: Please attach the image.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might following links can help you.

1. http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/
2. http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-apps/quick-action-demo/
3. http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that the popover remain open when orientation changes?

Comment: @RahulGupta, I think its possible. You need to set some flag for whether its open in portrait mode? Then when orientation changes, check that flag, and reopen it by implicit call. :)